# ios nsarrya with nsdictionary has <null> elements

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have nsarray with dictionaries but I'm getting  elements in the array. if I run this line:

```
po [ myArray valueForKeyPath:@"today"]
```

I get this output:

```
<null>,
<null>,
<null>,
{
    sales = @"1";
    typeOfSale = @"onLine";
}
)
```

I try this:

```
[myArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];
```

but didn't work.

any of you knows can I remove the  ?

Comment: Just write a loop.  Then you can control what goes on.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove objects identical NSNull because your array does not contain NSNull. It contains something like an NSDictionary which doesn't have a value for @"today".

The most simple solution would be to do something like this:

```
[myArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"today != nil"]];
```

Comment: it work but I need to do it in all the array. I'm populating the array with a for loop for (NSString *key in myDict) . How can use the key in the predicatedWIthFormat?

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue with the following line:

[myArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@ "%K  != %@", key,  nil]];